# fail to use xpath to find element in webdriver

Tags: java, html, xpath

any help is appreciated.

I am wondering if the firebug copy xpath always working for webdriver.

I have a page with a list, I could get the full xpath to find the first two elements, but could not do the same for 3, 4th.

For 3rd one it's not working:

```
WebElement element3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody[2]/tr[3]/td[5]/div"));
```

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody[2]/tr[3]/td[5]/div"}

My HTML:

```
<tr class="GKWRNW-BEX GKWRNW-BLYD GKWRNW-BELB GKWRNW-BON"> 
<td class="GKWRNW-BKW GKWRNW-BIYD x-grid-cell-first explorerGridRow" style="" cellindex="0"> 
<td class="GKWRNW-BKW GKWRNW-BIYD undefined x-treegrid-column explorerGridRow" style="" cellindex="1"> 
<div class="GKWRNW-BMW GKWRNW-BJYD" style=""> 
<div id="x-auto-390" class="GKWRNW-BPLC"> 
<div class="GKWRNW-BMLC"> 
<img style="height: 18px; width: 0px;" src="data:image/gif;=="> 
<img class="GKWRNW-BOLC" style="width: 16px" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0l=="> <span class="GKWRNW-BILC"></span>
```

Comment: Here is its html snippet:
<tr class="GKWRNW-BEX GKWRNW-BLYD GKWRNW-BELB GKWRNW-BON">
<td class="GKWRNW-BKW GKWRNW-BIYD x-grid-cell-first explorerGridRow" style="" cellindex="0">
<td class="GKWRNW-BKW GKWRNW-BIYD undefined x-treegrid-column explorerGridRow" style="" cellindex="1">
<div class="GKWRNW-BMW GKWRNW-BJYD" style="">
<div id="x-auto-390" class="GKWRNW-BPLC">
<div class="GKWRNW-BMLC">
<img style="height: 18px; width: 0px;" src="data:image/gif;==">
<img class="GKWRNW-BOLC" style="width: 16px" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0l==">
<span class="GKWRNW-BILC"></span>

Comment: You should put your code in your question, not in comments

Comment: did you modify your DOM element after the code has been written? If any DOM element is added or removed then most likely the `x-path` will change too.

Answer (score 0):

Using x-path to find an element is not an efficient way. Because any changes in DOM element (eg. - adding or removing of a new DOM element like a `div`) will results in a change in x-path.

So better to use `id` to each DOM element and use `By.id()` -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("someId::button"));
```

Comment: 1. I tried to put the code in question but it somehow complains the code is not complete while I didn't want to put all code into the question.                                                                                                      2. thanks for above answers, I understand xpath may not be the best way to find the element, but for this particular case, I did not make any DOM, change, I gave it enough time to load (because other elements were found fine), could anyone think of what else could go wrong with the xpath approach for finding the element ? thanks in advance.

Comment: also when I inspect the DOM Panel for web element from the firebug, it shows id="" , seems id is null to me.   also itemID = "" as well.   the only way appears to  me is by xpath